# linq to entity framework with join

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have in my DB 2 tables:

1. Documents (Document_Id ,document_Name)
2. Person_Documents (person_ID ,Documet_Id document_Done)

I use entity framework and ,and I want to fill `DataGrid` with the data `document_Name` and `document_Done`,

I have tried the following with no results:

```
      vagEntities projectE = new vagEntities();
      var doc = from c in projectE.Person_Documents                   
          join cw in projectE.Documents on c.Document_Id equals cw.Document_Id
          where c.Person_Id == 150
          select c;

      DocGrid.ItemsSource = doc;
```

Please, where am I wrong?
un the xaml i write this

```
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Document_Name}" MinWidth="100"   Header="document"  />

            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Binding="{Binding Path=Document_done}" Header="Do" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking to project your result to an anonymous type like this:

Update - project to concrete class

```
public class NameAndDone {
  public string document_Name { get; set; }
  public bool document_Done { get; set; }
}

var doc = from c in projectE.Person_Documents
          join cw in projectE.Documents on c.Document_Id equals cw.Document_Id
          where c.Person_Id == 150
          select new NameAndDone {
            cw.document_Name,
            c.document_Done
          };
```

Comment: Two answers do not work, this response is an error : A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Document_done' of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]'.

Comment: Maybe someone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: @user1095549 - The Binding path is case sensitive. In my example you need to change path to `Path=document_Name` and `Path=document_done`

Comment: The problem persists, and I'm going crazy, maybe you can fix the above code?

Comment: @user1095549 - Try projecting to a concrete class. I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, you saved me so much time!

Comment: can is it possible to bring back the changes from datagrid to EF and then call saveChanges()

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
  vagEntities projectE = new vagEntities();
  var doc = from c in projectE.Person_Documents                   
      from cw in projectE.Documents where c.Person_Id == 150 && c.Documents.Contains(cw)
      select c;

  DocGrid.ItemsSource = doc;
```